# Test an application behind a proxy server using Robot Framework and Selenium2Library

Tags: proxy, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework

I'm testing a web application behind a proxy server using both Robot Framework and Selenium2Library. In fact when the proxy is enabled in browser connexion setting , the keywords "Open browser" failed

when I disabled the Proxy server option , the browser windows is getting opened but i am not able to visit the application.

This happen with both IE en ff driver.

I want to know if there is any additional configuration to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Selenium2Library documentation gives an example of using a proxy using the [Create Webdriver](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Create%20Webdriver) keyword:

```
| | # use proxy for Firefox         
| | ${proxy}=            | Evaluate     | sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].Proxy() | sys, selenium.webdriver
| | ${proxy.http_proxy}= | Set Variable | localhost:8888    
| | Create Webdriver     | Firefox      | proxy=${proxy}
```